# Saving file with custom file extension in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a WPF application and I would like to save the values entered in the application whenever the user clicks on a 'Save Project' button that I have in my application. But, I need to save it with a different file extension such that only my application can open it and not other text editors (I don't want to save it as a .txt file). How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you just want to save the file with your own extension so that you can then create an association of that extension to your application? Or do you need some kind of security? Of course, whenever you save a file in C#, you always have to specify a full file name, including extension, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Are you saying that you want your own file extension for your application, for example, says the extension is *.myf and when you double click on any of .myf it will launch your application to open that file right?

Comment: @JerryLiang You're right. That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In a non-trivial application, this setup is usually configured in an installer software like InstallShield or Inno Setup.. etc You can search for "File Association" for the configurations.

Just give you a quick start on this, firstly we need to register the file association you want in windows registry so that when you double click on the file it will launch your application.

For a example below, assume that **.myf** is the extension you want to associate with. **myapp** is the name of your application and **C:\myapp.exe** is your executable file. Save this as a batch file like "registermyapp.bat" and run it. Note: you need to copy your wpf and renamed your wpf application executable file to this path!

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\.myf /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "myapp" /f
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\myapp\shell\open\command /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\myapp.exe\" \"%%1\"" /f
```

Then in your `App.xaml` you need to override OnStartup() method in order to get the input file name.

```
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var filename = e.Args[0];
            // do something with .myf file                
            var content = File.ReadAllText(filename);//just example
            ...
        }
```